# Android: Updating a ListView when the content of a SearchView is changed with results from Google Places API

Tags: java, android, android-listview, google-places-api, android-search

I am trying to update a ListView with Google Places API when the value of the SearchView is changed. There is a problem when the list view gets updated.

Here is my class, SearchFragment.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5fc885cca8426736888

onListItemClick gets the latitude and longitude of the item clicked by the user, and using a public interface of the fragment, it's passed to the activity.

The problem is that the ListView contains items that aren't in the list of predictions, even though I'm using the list of predictions that gets returned to update the ListView each time. If I click on something other than the first one, it will return the wrong coordinates, or the index will be out of range of the list of predictions, causing a null pointer exception on the first line of onListItemClick.

It doesn't seem like I'm going about this in the cleanest way. Could somebody please point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel the previous request when "onQueryTextChange" is called again.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I edit the SearchView slowly, so that each query has a chance to finish, it works as expected. I can't seem to figure out cancel the previous thread and stop it from updating the view. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: I tired this, and I'm having the same problem. This feels messy so I'd like to figure out how to handle it with an custom ArrayAdapter, or something different after I understand this. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9be6de0e68f98235ed48

Comment: you could use 'volley'. Used that library before and it's very handy especially for your approach.                      http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html